# A monostable multivibrator using two NPN transistors works as desired in LTSpice, but in reality is very different

Tags: transistors, multivibrator, monostable

I designed a simple monostable multivibrator to extend a pulse of width \$\approx\$ \$1{\mu}s\$, to \$8ms\$ (to illuminate an LED when something happens on a bus).

This is the circuit here, and the output as simulated with some background noise in LTSpice.

[image: The Schematic and the Simulation output]

Is there anything obvious as to why it does not work? I debugged the circuit meticulously for potential problems in assembly and cannot find any.

What I see at the output potential is essentially the same thing that is input. A pulse seems to propagate all the way to the output node, except that instead of being \$Ground\$ to \$V_{cc}\$, it's around \$Ground\$ to \$V_{cc} - 1.0V = 2.3V\$ and its pulse duration mimics the input very closely. I cannot adequately explain this. I would have assumed that if it worked, this potential should be around \$3.3V\$ as the right transistor is not biased and may only develop some weak diffusion. This means the potential that appears at the output should be the result of the divider of \$R_{O,2}\$ and \$R_2\$ with \$V_{be,q2}\$ not affecting this potential, this gives around \$3.20V\$.

The NPN transistors I am using are inside a `BC847BPN` package (`SOT363`) if that suggests anything I have missed. Also in reality, the resistors used for modelling the inputs for \$V_{cc}\$ and \$V_{noise}\$ are not present, and \$V_{noise}\$ is just to aid in the simulation.

\$C_3\$ was intended to be \$100n\$ but in reality I measured it to be \$180n\$, hence its odd value in the simulation. The voltage drop across the diode is \$0.7V\$ measured in reality also, and its reverse breakdown is 45V and supports \$200mA\$ in the forward direction.

Just to reiterate, my input pulse is positive from \$Ground\$ to \$3.3V\$ and I need the output to also be close in magnitude. I can pass it through a Schottky if need-be.

Image of the real circuit. The `DO-323` region has the `7` passives and diode, the `SOT-23` region has the two transistor packages `BC847BPN` on its top right and middle top locations.

[The photo of the circuit made up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvfkm.jpg)

Comment: Just checking here: is your power switched on? Reason I'm asking is because I think it would explain your output behavior.

Comment: I can verify this tomorrow when I have my scope handy, but the nodes on the dev board labelled with a \$+\$ are all internally the node \$V_{cc}\$ and so it should be present.

Comment: I think my 'Diode' may be a capacitor... Damned parts bin haha.